# Can we use DataStore<T> in PreferenceScreen?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, datastore

Same as title, I want to use [DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore) for storing a custom type `ServerPreferences` but I don't want to use `PreferenceDataStore` separately for it.

Is there any way I can use `DataStore<T>` with `PreferenceScreen`?

Below is an example of the settings fragment:

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

    @Inject lateinit var serverPrefsStore: DataStore<ServerPreferences>

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {

        /**
         * This gives an error of type mismatch
         * Required: PreferenceDataStore? Found: DataStore<ServerPreferences>
         */
        preferenceManager.preferenceDataStore = serverPrefsStore
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.server_settings, rootKey)
    }
}
```

Comment: PreferenceManager's confusingly named PreferenceDataStore (no relation whatsoever to DataStore library) is an interface, so you could theoretically create a bridge to wrap DataStore to work as a PreferenceDataStore. It would be very complicated to get right because PreferenceDataStore is not based on coroutines. Hopefully they are planning an update to the Preferences library to support it, or else a rewrite based on Compose that uses DataStore instead of SharedPreferences. I have suspected they are working on that 2nd one because the library hasn't been updated in a long time.

Comment: True, their naming around this is very confusing.

Also, I thought of implementing a custom wrapper around it but read in another post that it can be pain due to the different behaviours of both of them and some types do not save correctly.


I hope they release some solution for this, it is so stupid that we can't use both of them. So, I'll probably need to use PreferenceDataStore then for now.

Comment: @tenfour04 Have any news about it?

Comment: @Viewed, I'm not sure what you mean. I am not part of Google, so I don't know anything you don't know about it.